# E2E testing remote AngularJS application

Tags: testing, angularjs, cross-domain, karma-runner, end-to-end

I'm trying to realize E2E testing of existing *AngularJS* application with *Karma Test Runner*. My application is located on `host1.internal` and I'm on `host2.internal`. So in my karma config file I have:

```
proxies = {
  '/': 'http://host1.internal/',
};
```

Before logging in it shows different `<div>`'s that are inside of `index.html`, but after logging in it hides all visible before divs with `ng-hide='loggedIn'`. The problem is that partial view files are being fetched for `<div ng-view>` with *AngularJS* routing config like that:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    controller: overviewController,
    templateUrl: 'views/overview.html',
    // templateUrl: 'http://host2.internal/views/overview.html',
    title_prefix: 'Home'
  }).
 etc. etc. etc.
```

and I get these errors in my browser's console:

```
GET http://localhost:9876/views/homepage.html 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see in routing config code snippet, I've tried getting templates with full URL, but unfortunately, the request is not simple `GET`, it's `OPTIONS` (I'm not sure why?) and I'm getting error about good old *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header.

How do I configure proxy in *Karma* config correctly so that I could fetch these static files? Or any other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: When you start karma do you see a warning message concerning urlRoot?

Comment: `[WARN] config - urlRoot normalized to "/e2e/"`, but that's because I've put urlRoot to that in karma config file. Without urlRoot it can't even load my application front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution to this problem, I've put `$templateCache` to use. That way all html files are being loaded in one *.js* file together with all the rest scripts on my `index.html`.

If you use Grunt like me, look at [grunt-html2js](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-html2js).

Cheers!